# Как убрать все панели в приложении под android 4.0.4 (ICS)?

Tags: android

Приложение должно показываться на полном экране без панелей. Для этого прописываю в манифесте `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` для всего приложения. В android 4.1.2 все панели убираются.
Когда ставлю то же самое приложение на 4.0.4. Верхняя панель (как я понимаю, она принадлежит activity) убирается, а нижняя(системная) остается.

Можно ли скрыть системную панель в этой версии андроида? Можно ли сделать это без root'а?

Обновление: нашла следующие варианты:

```
//Скрывает значки на панели, вернее превращает их в маленькие точки, панель не скрывает
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE );
//Судя по описанию должна скрывать панель, но у меня, опять-таки не работает
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
//То же самое, тоже не работает
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Решения пока нет.

Comment: что это за нижняя системная? покажи скрин?

Comment: @Gorets, изображение выложить, увы не могу, но вот ссылка просто из интернета 

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vgGNkW9zg_Y/TwWQ2zAEF6I/AAAAAAAACwQ/R6uZIEnQdfE/s1600/ActionBar_on.png

То, что сверху, как я понимаю - ActionBar. А снизу - системная панель.

Comment: @rasmisha, то есть нужно или рутить или обновлять, но для этого тоже рутить? Если так, то это прискорбно.

Comment: а как без них выйти из приложения? фуллскрин можно попробовать в коде активити сделать

Comment: @Gorets, в более новой системе проблемы с выходом не было. То есть панель не показывалась, но кнопки back и home исправно работали. На самом деле даже невозможность выйти из программы не была бы проблемой, все равно в конечном итоге нужно делать на ее основе свой лаунчер.
Идеальным вариантом было бы иметь возможность в ходе работы программы показывать или прятать эту панель и навесить на нее только нужные настройки, либо скрыть ее полностью и сделать свою.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается, убирается или нет status bar зависит от значения параметра 
`tv.hideStatusBar.enable` в файле **build.prop**. 
Если его значение равняется `true`, то панель убирается просто установкой темы с Fullsceen или другими стандартными способами, если же значение `false`, то не убирается, а максимум сворачивается в точки с помощью

```
View.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE );
```

Поменять значение `tv.hideStatusBar.enable` без root доступа не представляется мне возможным. Получив права суперпользователя, я изменила значение с помощью приложения **build.prop Editor**. Теперь все работает как нужно.

Выполнение

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui"});
```

у меня не сработало. Появляется предупреждение, что приложение потребовало root-права, но панель не убирается.

Использование скрытого api:

```
SystemProperties.set("tv.hideStatusBar.enable", "true");
```

тоже не помогло, просто ничего не происходит. Хотя, может быть для принятия изменений требуется перезагрузка. Во всяком случае, сторонний редактор перезагрузку для применения потребовал. Но, может быть, нужны еще какие-то особые права.

Например, системные приложения могут убирать status bar "на лету". Например системная Activity PositionSetting поступает следующим образом:

```
  protected void onPause()
  {
    SystemProperties.set("vplayer.hideStatusBar.enable", "false");
    super.onPause();
  }

  protected void onResume()
  {
    SystemProperties.set("vplayer.hideStatusBar.enable", "true");
    super.onResume();
  }
```

тем самым скрывая панель только на время своего исполнения. Однако, выполнение того же самого в моем приложении не дает никакого эффекта.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему нельзя. Была даже статья на эту тему на хабре: [Kiosk Mode приложения на Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149561/).

Answer (score 2):

Как это нельзя, очень даже можно - перед подключением лейаута в активити нужно прописать пару строк

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо

Comment: только не работает на 4.0.4

Comment: ну у меня 4.1.1 и всё работает, а что этто вообще за версия 4.0.4? вот в SDK менеджере вижу 4.0.3 и потом сразу 4.1.2 можно скачать

Comment: стойте, вопрос то про 4.0.х был) зы не все тестят на эмуляторе, 4.0.4 есть)

Comment: есть 4.0.4, он объединен в SDK с 4.0.3 (API Level 15, ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но с дополнительным хаком. 
Есть программу Hide Status bar http://ppareit.github.com/HideBar/

Comment: @Artemis в вопросе: Можно ли сделать это без root'а?

В ответе: This application needs ROOT! Only install and use when you have root+busybox+superuser!

Answer (score 0):

Нижнюю панель (не верхнюю шапку) - там где находятся кнопки home/menu/back и проч. невозможно убрать.

Эти кнопки - фактически единственные кнопки управления приложением (особенно home) - они фиксированы на уровне оси и программным способом их убрать невозможно.

Как кое-кто мог заметить - эти кнопки не появляются только на устройствах с физическими кнопками home/menu/back.

Comment: Как по поняла из вот этого: http://androidextrememodding.blogspot.ru/2012/10/hide-status-bar-in-android-ics.html
Для телефонов есть возможность убрать status bar, а для планшетов нет. На практике же, будет отнесено устройство к телефонам или к планшетам не зависит от наличия кнопок или разрешения, а зависит только от воли производителя.
Вот у меня две очень похожие приставки: кнопки одинаковые, разрешение одинаковое,  версия андроида одна и та же, только сборки разные, но на одной все работает, а на другой, по всей видимости, запрещено.